# Handling zombies with SIGCHLD

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, signals

In my program, I am listening to incoming SIGCHLD signals to avoid zombies.

Code :

```
void myhandler(int signo)
{   
    printf("test");
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
        ++count;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    struct sigaction sigchld_action;
    memset(&sigchld_action,0,sizeof(sigchld_action));
    sigchld_action.sa_handler = &myhandler;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD,&sigchld_action,NULL);

    if(fork() == 0){
        exit(0);
    }
    if(fork()==0){
        exit(0);
    }
    if(fork()==0){
        exit(0);
    }


    while(wait(NULL) > 0)
    ++count;

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, number of forked childs and number of output of printf("test") does not match sometimes. Number of forked childs are greater than number printf("test").

Is this code segment guarentees that there will be no zombies? If it is, how it can achieve this? It is not printing the correct number of "test". Is waitpid() clears the dead childs more than once inside the while?

What happens, when this signal handler called, at the same time another child can be died. Signal will blocked by default.(while handler is running, another child can die). Does the waitpid clear the process whose signal sent when signal handler is running?

Also, counter is not equal. (static volatile int) or I tried atomic integer.

Comment: You can't safely use stdio functions like `printf()` in a signal handler, btw.

Comment: @Shawn Yes I know, but If use atomic counter, result is same.

Comment: If a second child process dies before the parent handles the first SIGCHLD, the second SIGCHLD is lost.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica So in this case, in your example, there will be one zombie? or waitpid clears the second died process ? If this handler invokes 5 times for example, is there any chance that clearing 6 child process?

Comment: He simply means that the pending signals of the same type are not queued, they are discarded. Also, signal handler masks the signal for the duration of handler (unless you explicitly prevent it from doing so). So they arrive but hever get handled in time. You don't reap all the children this way — zombies occur.

Comment: @vtronko Thank you. Is there any way to avoid whole zombies ?

Comment: Actually, my last statement was wrong, it may happen that all children are still reaped in the while loop. Even if handler is only called once. Checking how many times handler is called is not a valid metrics here. Your code is safe this way after all, sorry for confusion in some of the statements

Comment: @vtronko My idea is this, even if the SIGCHLD is lost, the waitpid inside the handler can (?) sees this dead process(whose signal is lost) and clears him. So, for example, if there are 5 childs, but handler invoked 3 times. Can we say that, other processes reaped in the while loop by waitpid inside the handler ? Are you saying that ? If it is, there should be no zombie. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Root2A that's what I think, yes. If there're no more children to reap, it quits handler, but when SIGCHLD occurs again — you will just enter handler once more.

Comment: @vtronko Thank you. For example, waitpid clear the process whose signal is not comed yet. What happens to this signal ? Sender of this signal is reaped. Actuallay it is a different question but, I really wondered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different things are going on:

1. `printf` isn't async-signal-safe, so you shouldn't call it from a signal handler. Replace it with `write`.
2. You're only incrementing `count` once in the signal handler. If you want to know how many processes died, you need to increment it in your `while` loop instead.

Try this code:

```
void handler(int signo)
{   
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        write(1, "test", 4); /* technically this may result in a partial write and you should loop it, but in practice I think this'll be fine for this example */
        ++count;
    }
}
```

With that code, you'll probably have no zombies and have the right number of `test`s and the right value in `count`. However, there's one more race condition: if between the final call to `waitpid` and the end of the signal handler, another child process dies, then no `SIGCHLD` will be received, so it will be a zombie until the one after it dies too. A solution to this edge case is much more complex and depends on how the rest of your application is structured.

Comment: Result is same, in 5 processes count changes between 2-3-5. But I add a infinite loop to the end of the parent to avoid the terminating the parent, then I run ps and I dont see any zombies. If counts is lower than number of processes, how there is not any zombie ?

Comment: @Root2A Can you edit your question to include a full program instead of just a signal handler? Then it might be more clear what's going on.

Comment: @Root2A Two bits of funny business: 1. `handler` vs. `myhandler`. 2. If you want your signal handler to do the waiting, then why is there a `wait` in `main`?

Comment: I want to wait until my childs to terminate. I remove the wait, add a sleep, but again same problem.

Comment: @Root2A
Do you have a specific reason to do that in signal handler though? You can just move that non-hanging waitpid outside and get away with no race conditions. Just checking, in case if you are confused into thinking that signal handler is only way to go.

Comment: @vtronko I want to know the reason and solution (if it can). Yes, there can be easy and better solution for this like you said. This handler seems that it reapes all the zombies. I add a infinite loop end of the parent to avoid terminating it, and check with ps command.  I do not see any zombies, but, count value is not gives me the right value . So how it reaped all the childs ?

Comment: @Root2A There are never orphan processes. When a process dies while it still has children that aren't yet reaped, the children get adopted (usually by `init`). You're not seeing zombies because `init` is reaping them after the parent exits.

Comment: `write(1, "test", 4);` would probably be better as `write(1, "test\n", 5);`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Question edited. I add new while end of the parent. So now, I have the right value of count and parent do not exit if there is at least 1 child. Am I right ? So there is no chance that childs become an orphan? Am I right ? Thank you.

Comment: @Root2A Processes on UNIX and Linux can never, ever become true orphans. Any time a process would otherwise become an orphan, another process always adopts it. The kernel enforces this.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica last while loop, end of the main, Isnt that guarentees that parents die before childs at every time ?

Comment: @Root2A no, that actually causes the opposite.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica oh sorry, yes. I waits all childs to terminate now, and I am getting the right count value.  But there is a small window,for this version too, that this program do not reapes all zombies since race condition that you mentioned in your answer right ?

Comment: @Root2A Your latest version with `while(wait(NULL) > 0)` at the end of `main` will never exit before all of its children do. (Of course, it could still be `kill -9`d or something.)